# Vertically centered line for a text

Tags: css

In a log-in/register box I have to separate two buttons with a text like this.

[image: Log in / Register box]

With my HTML code being:

```
<button class="facebookSux">Ingresa con Facebook</button>
<label>o si prefieres</label>
<button class="register">Regístrate con tus datos</button>
```

How can I get the horizontal line for the label only with CSS?

One solution that I have considered is using a linear gradient appropriately but there have to be a more elegant way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a container around these three tags that can be styled too, in which case I propose **[this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/DWycS/2)**.

[image: Screenshot]

Markup (unaltered):

```
<div>
    <button>Ingresa con Facebook</button>
    <label>o si prefieres</label>
    <button>Regístrate con tus datos</button>
</div>
```

Style sheet:

```
div {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
button {
    width: 100%;
}
label {
    padding: 0 1em;
    position: relative;
}
label::before,
label::after {
    width: 125px; /* =250/2 */
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
}
label::after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Short after posting this question I came up with a solution that closely resembles yours. I am picking this answer for being the only one not needing to add garbage (empty elements) HTML for styling. In short, you actually answered exactly what I was asking.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly use 2 divs and positioning

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jsBDD/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="text">Hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}

.line {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.text {
    background: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 128px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: In demo, when I add more text, text no longer remains centered. Atleast the horizontal lines are not equi-lengthed.

Comment: @SushantGupta if you know what this means, it needs to resized manually, the OP doesn't have any dynamic text

Comment: @MrAlien Actually I don't know CSS. I was just looking at JSFiddle demo of yours, and I didn't got the output what I expected. So I thought to share what I saw. Anyways, you can ignore my opinion since I am not even worth calling CSS newbie :P By the way, Congrats, for your new privilige

Comment: @SushantGupta hehe nah nah, actually in CSS when you use `position: absolute;` it gets out of the document flow, you resize it, doesn't affect other elements on the page so you need to manually to it :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21019/discussion-between-mr-alien-and-sushant-gupta)

Comment: Didn't say it was wrong, I only ment to say that your solution isn't complete yet for implementation in the real world. The downvote implies the answer not being very usefull in my personal opinion. By the way, your answer ís partially wrong: you assume `.text` positions relatively to `.line`, but it doesn't. Better place the second div within the first then.

Comment: @NGLN Oh yes right, I've missed out the wrapper, editing the answer right away, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<hr />` tag for this. It is possible to style the `<hr />` tag as a single black line. With the use of css you could place them in the right position.

Styling the `<hr />` tag as a black line:

```
hr {
        border: 1px; 
        height: 1px; 
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: `border: 0px;` is also valid.

Answer (score 0):

Using this: http://jsfiddle.net/tErMn/

You have dynamic text positioning and the line with css only.

The trick is in `display: inline-block;` , `margin: auto;` and `z-index`;

HTML

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="text">Hello</div>
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

.text{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;

}

.line {
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```